# wait or sleep in javascript

Tags: jquery, post, sleep, wait

as I can pause this code of 1 second before running the "post function".

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#Button").click(function() {

        /*1 second pause before executing the post */
        $.post(url,{Par1=5},function(e){
        });
    });
});
```

Regards.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setTimeout or http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout`:

```
$("#Button").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        /* 1 second pause before executing the post */
        $.post(url, { Par1 = 5 }, function(e) { } );
    }, 1000);
});
```

Also, assuming you only want multiple clicks of the button to send 1 request at a time, you can use `clearTimeout` to prevent your site being flooded. Try this

```
var timeout;
$("#Button").click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $.post(url, { Par1 = 5 }, function(e) { } );
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) with an argument of `1000` milliseconds:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#Button").click(function() {

        setTimeout(function(){
            $.post(url,{Par1=5},function(e){
                // ...
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setTimeout(code,millisec,lang)` function. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) some informations.

As result on the comments you will find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) a better summary, without the `lang` parameter.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $.post(url,{Par1=5},function(e){
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: setTimeout doesn't expect the language as it's third argument. W3Schools is wrong, like it often is. Please don't use it as a reference.

Comment: @Paulpro Well, Microsoft use them also as optional, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/ms536753.aspx). Maybe it's not that wrong.

Comment: @hofmeister That's essentially a bug in IE... IE is almost as bad at adhering to W3C recommendations as W3Schools is at mentioning them.